# How to move the axis

Tags: edit-mode

I started a project by importing a .dae object and have completed the changes I want however everything is at the bottom of the 'workspace' (see image below) and I have searched everywhere (probably not) to determine how to the axis (X and Y) to the center of the workspace. I can move my object and move the 3d cursor but cannot work out how to center the axis.

[image]

Comment: Hold Shift + Middle Mouse Button (scroll wheel) and move your mouse up (pan camera)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the view to pivot around the object, you could select the object and press <kbd>**Numpad .**</kbd> (period) to center the view on that object.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think to try and other keys on the numpad (only the numeric ones).   Can I slip in another question here?  How to snap the 3d cursor to the intersection of all axis (trying to select it and move using shift RMB is a hit and miss affair).

Comment: @John *Object > Snap > Cursor to World Origin* :)

Comment: Thanks Jachym. I had tried using shift S so I was 'barking up the wrong tree'